# Applescript: cut character and paste within span tags

Tags: applescript, textwrangler

I've been automating a process that we do for work that involves converting word documents to html files in TextWrangler. I've got everything sorted except for one final step, which involves moving the first character of the article inside of span tags (Boss's design choice, and the website doesn't support CSS that isn't inline or I'd just use first-letter).

Anyway, the HTML looks like this:

```
<p style='color: #444; font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 1.8em; font-weight: bold;'>
<img style='display: block; float: right; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 15px; width: 475px;' src='*****.jpg' alt='' width='950' height='713' />
<span style='color: #444; float: left; font-size: 3em;'></span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at rhoncus velit. Sed velit libero, venenatis non ornare ac, egestas vitae quam.</p>
```

The idea would just be to move the first letter following the closing span tag to inside the span tag, but I've looked around and don't really have any idea where to begin.

Edit: This might be made easier knowing in that the number of characters prior to the necessary letter in the line won't ever change. So maybe finding a way to isolate the nth character in the line and go from there?

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly example, you'll want to polish it a bit:

```
set htmlText to "... your HTML ..."

set endSpanLength to 7
set endSpanPos to offset of "</span>" in htmlText
set firstCharPos to (endSpanPos + endSpanLength + 1)
set firstChar to character firstCharPos of htmlText

set oldEndSpan to "</span>" & linefeed & firstChar
set newEndSpan to firstChar & "</span>" & linefeed

findAndReplaceInText(htmlText, oldEndSpan, newEndSpan)

on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```

Comment: The script gets stuck on setting firstCharPos because the first character is outside of htmlText. Instead I asked textwrangler to process the first line that contains span tags and return the whole line, but the script is getting stuck on the offset line

`error "Can’t make {«class MdfT»:missing value, «class CpyL»:\"<p><img src='*****.jpg' /><span></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
\"} into type string." number -1700 from {«class MdfT»:missing value, «class CpyL»:"<p><img src='*****.jpg' /><span></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
"} to string`

Comment: For some reason, I thought you're working with string in your script. Could you please share an example of how your object with HTML looks like? You might also want to add an information that it is an object to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to AppleScript and not too savvy yet.  Here's a paste with everything I have so far, let me know if you're looking for something else? https://pastebin.com/wRp7vaxQ . Here's what happens: The code is pasted at the beginning of an article, and that's all the formatting that happens. I'd like to make another function that will take the first letter after the closing span tag and move it inside. The first letter will change with each article, which (i think) is what caused the issue with the original script. Thank you, and let me know if I didn't give you what you need.